# Upgrading GWT to latest version

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-ext

2 years back We have developed an application using `GWT 1.4.6` and `GWT-Ext 2.0.3` frameworks.

Now our management is thinking of upgrading these two frameworks. 
But the Gwt-Ext website states that the development of Gwt-Ext has been superseded by `smart GWT`.

I just want to ask that if we update/upgrade from `GWT 1.4.6` to `GWT 2.2`, whether Gwt-Ext 2.0.3 will work or not ?

if anyone have any experience in this please give me some inputs to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same situation, we wanted to upgrade GWT 1.4 to 2.1.0 and we had GWT-Ext 2.0.3 which was the end of that project but there was 2.0.5 available though with minor changes.

The transition was not smooth but it was not also worst. We tried to attach new plug-in to our source in Eclipse and it complained about:

1. Removal of some unnecessary inherts in x.gwt.xml (main entry file)
2. The public folder was replaced with the new Ext 2.0.5 files
3. We were using ftr-gwt libarary where there were some mismatch with the method signatures and return types. But were simple.

And I don't remember running into any serious problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was in GWT 2.1 that Google updated their built in interface widgets dramatically.  Because of this, my experience has been that the various widget libraries (GXT, SmartGWT) have had to update their libraries to support gwt 2.2.  So my guess for your question is that GWT-EXT 2.0.3 probably will not work with GWT 2.2 or the newer 2.3.